# How can I draw/fill solid trend colour / vertical column under a candlestick ( instead of background ) to indicate trend on ema shift?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

The problem is that I do not want the background color to extend above the candlestick, and for the background color to be below the candlestick , including the wick.

this is an example of my code :

```
 //@version=5 
indicator(title='EMA', overlay=true)
s20_ema = ta.ema(close, 20) 
s80ema = ta.ema(close, 80)
plot(s20_ema,color=color.green)
plot(s80ema,color=color.red)
longCond = ta.crossover(s20_ema, s80ema) 
shortCond = ta.crossunder(s20_ema, s80ema)

bgcolor(s20_ema>s80ema?color.new(color.green,0):s20_ema<s80ema?color.new(color.red,0):na)
barcolor(s20_ema>s80ema?color.new(color.green,0):s20_ema<s80ema?color.new(color.red,0):na)

plotshape(series=longCond, title='BUY', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text='BUY', size=size.small) 
plotshape(series=shortCond, title='SELL', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text='SELL', size=size.small)
```

Tried to research background color function and parse through documentation, tried to search in images and nobody seems to have colour under the candle, tried searching internet. not sure how to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bgcolor` cannot fill a limited range, it colorizes the whole vertical span.

Not sure whether this is what you meant:
[image]

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © moebius1977

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
s20_ema = ta.ema(close, 20) 
s80_ema = ta.ema(close, 80)
p20 = plot(s20_ema,color=color.green)
p80 = plot(s80_ema,color=color.red)
longCond = ta.crossover(s20_ema, s80_ema) 
shortCond = ta.crossunder(s20_ema, s80_ema)



barcolor(s20_ema>s80_ema?color.new(color.green,0):s20_ema<s80_ema?color.new(color.red,0):na)


colorize = s20_ema > s80_ema
fillColor = colorize ? color.green : na
fillBottom = low /2
fillTop = math.min(open, close)
plotBottom = plot(fillBottom, color = color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 100)) 
plotTop = plot(fillTop, color = color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 100)) 
fill(plotBottom, plotTop, top_color = fillColor, bottom_color = fillColor, top_value = fillTop, bottom_value = fillBottom)
```